# glGenVertexArrays causes crash

Tags: opengl, c++, glut, mingw, glew

My code keeps crashing at runtime, I have done some creative debugging and determined that it was the glGenVertexArrays that was causing the crash, I've looked around and come across some answers that told me to enable experimental mode in GLEW but that didn't work, as far as I can tell my graphics card supports it, my opengl version is 3.1. I'm using freeGLUT and GLEW

here's the code, the line in question is 45
http://hastebin.com/rekizejuza.cpp

```
std::cout << "made it here\r\n";
glGenVertexArrays(1, &meshID);
std::cout << "not here here\r\n";
glBindVertexArray(meshID);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Just edited the question to include the code

Comment: @JordanLaPrise You need to include the code into the question itself!

Comment: BTW, looking at the code provided in the link, I've spotted another error, which doesn't seem to be related to the `glGenVertexArrays` problem, but nonetheless would crash your app if it wen't on. Check line 57 `delete [] ids;`. You are deleting a local variable that was declared on the stack, at line 49 `unsigned int ids[4];`. Your compiler is probably not complaining about it, but this is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Hello my friend! Probably you forgot to add `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` and this causes openGL crashes when calling glGenVertexArrays();

I hope I have helped! See ya!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common reason for null pointer dereferences on calls to newer OpenGL functions is that they are provided by an extension wrangler library like GLEW through function pointers that are dynamically loaded at runtime.

In order for them to be initialized, you need to run the initialization function of GLEW.

The correct place to call `glewInit()` is after you've gotten an OpenGL context and have made it current, but before you use any of the extension function pointers it exposes.

Comment: I did run glewInit, I'm using it with freeGlut, so would the right place to init glew be after I've created the window but before I've started the event loop?

Comment: Yes, right after freeGLUT is up would be a good place to call it. Make sure to check the return value for any initialization error.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned to be using GLEW. If so, the `glGenVertexArrays` symbol should be just a plain global variable of type function pointer. To know if it is available, you can just test it for null:

```
if (glGenVertexArrays == NULL)
{
    // chances are you don't have this feature...
}
```

If it is null, then either you have a problem with GLEW or the feature is likely not supported in your system.

In case you don't have VAOs, you can still render pretty much in the same way. Just remove the VAO calls and remember to always reset the vertex format before drawing. I.e.: `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Also, Make sure you have the most recent GL diver. It might help.

Comment: Well crap, it says it's not supported but I have gl 3.1 and from what I understood VAOs were introduced in 2.1 why would I not have them?

Comment: Oh nvm, I tried calling it after initializing GLEW and it wasn't null

Comment: What about glGetError() did it return anything before/after the failure?

Comment: no error before, if an error happened after I wouldn't know because the entire program comes to a halt and stops responding at that point

Comment: Is the problem fixed now? If yes, mark the answer correct.

Comment: From the comment above, it sounds like the problem was that @JordanLaPrise was calling glGenVertexArrays before calling glewInit() (and thereby setting the value of the glGenVertexArrays function pointer).

Comment: @TrevorPowell no that's not what was happening, he asked me to check the variable and see if I have support for the function, the first time it said I didn't have support, but I realized I was trying to check if I had support before initializing glew, in which case it says you don't have support for anything, but when I moved the check to after I init glew it says I have support, so the function itself is still not working, I just know I have support for the function now.

Comment: @JariKomppa no my problem is still unsolved

Comment: @JordanLaPrise, would you by any chance be calling the code that uses `glGenVertexArrays` in another thread other than the main thread?